# javascript eval - how to assign value to object property?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic object property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

I have an object like this

```
var localAppConfig = {
    wallet:0,
    paySomeone:0,
    payBills:0,
    accounts:0,
    moveMoney:0,
    alerts:0,
    offers:0,
    checkIn:0
};
```

I want to set value 1 for particular elements within this `localAppConfig`

Which element needs to be set is retrieved from the `json` - which arrives from the server.

say, I want to set value = 1 for wallet, paySomeone, payBills, alerts, offers, checkIn

These are retirved from the `json` like

```
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var name = list[i].handle;
        var accessor = eval('localAppConfig.'+name);
        eval('localAppConfig.'+name)=1;
    }
```

`var name` contains name of the element and I am able to access its value correctly,

How can I set the value using javascript?

I tried `accessor=1` but its not working.

Thanks :)

Comment: _EVIL_ roams the world: "When all you have is the eval hammer, everything looks like your thumb"

Comment: Noooooooooooooooooooooo!

Comment: hate `eval()` guys, don't hate me :p

Comment: @AdityaParab: I don't hate anybody, and I don't hate `eval`, I hate the way `eval` is abused by many: the only time `eval` is acceptable is to support `JSON` in older browsers. (ps: I din't down-vote)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : Its ok :) ... I didn't know the other syntax to access object property the time I posted this.. Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyhow: try this on for size:

```
localAppConfig[name] = 1;//where name is a variable of choice, it's value will be used as the propertyname
```

And again:

-When all you have is the eval hammer, everything looks like your thumb. 
–Brendan Eich in response to: we should encourage use of eval() rather than the Function constructor for dynamic creation of functions.

But why use a list of the properties? you might as well use a `for...in` loop: in case of objects, like yours, it's perfectly all right. 
As long as you check `.hasOwnProperty`, too:

```
for (var prop in localAppConfig)
{
    if (localAppConfig.hasOwnProperty(name))
    {
        //set, delete... do whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do this instead:

```
var accessor = localAppConfig[name];
localAppConfig[name] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `localAppConfig[name] = 1;`

It's just a javascript object, no need to use `eval()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval()`.  You can add a property by referencing the index of that value within your object.  If it doesn't exist then it will be created, otherwise the value will be overridden.

Try the following instead:

```
// localAppConfig[list[i].handle] = 1; 

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){         
    localAppConfig[list[i].handle] = 1;
}
```

Or if you intend to reference the variable in another place then set a variable with the value of `list[i].handle`:

```
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    var name = list[i].handle;        
    var accessor = localAppConfig[name];    
    localAppConfig[name] = 1;
}
```